# Writing Trigger logic in Apex class and calling the apex calling in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger APTS_ProposalLineItem on Proposal_Line_Item__c (after insert, after delete, after undelete, after update) {

if (Trigger.IsAfter && Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUndelete  ) {
    APTS_ProposalLineItem_Handler_raj.AfterInsert(Trigger.new);
}
else  if( Trigger.IsDelete){
  APTS_ProposalLineItem_Handler_raj.AfterUpdate(Trigger.old);  
} 
else if(Trigger.IsAfter && Trigger.IsUpdate)
{
   APTS_ProposalLineItem_Handler_raj.AfterInsert(Trigger.new); 
    APTS_ProposalLineItem_Handler_raj.AfterUpdate(Trigger.old);  
}}


public class APTS_ProposalLineItem_Handler_raj {

public static void AfterInsert(list<Proposal_Line_Item__c> proli){

  AllAfter(proli); 
}

public static void AfterUpdate(list<Proposal_Line_Item__c> proli){

  AllAfter(proli); 
}

public static void AllAfter(list<Proposal_Line_Item__c> proli){

    set<id>  ChapterID = new set<id>();

    for (Proposal_Line_Item__c p : proli){
        if (p.chapters__c != NULL )
        {
            ChapterID.add(p.chapters__c);
        }
    }

    list<chapter__C>   ChapterList =new list<chapter__c>();

    for(chapter__C ChpQuery:[select id, TotalLinePrice__c,TotalTrucks__c, (Select Id, LinePrice__c,NumberofTrucks__c,chapters__c from Proposal_Line_Items__r where chapters__c != NULL) from chapter__c where id IN:ChapterID ])
    {
        chapter__C chapt=new chapter__C();
        chapt.id=ChpQuery.Id;
        system.debug('chpquery'+chpquery.Proposal_Line_Items__r);
        chapt.TotalLinePrice__c =0;
        chapt.TotalTrucks__c = 0;
        if(ChpQuery.Proposal_Line_Items__r.size()>0){
            for(Proposal_Line_Item__c PLILoop: ChpQuery.Proposal_Line_Items__r ){

                //Updating Line Price  on  chapters
                if(PLILoop.LinePrice__c != NULL) {
                    chapt.TotalLinePrice__c += PLILoop.LinePrice__c;

                }
                else{
                    chapt.TotalLinePrice__c = 0;
                }

                if(PLILoop.NumberofTrucks__c != NULL) {
                    chapt.TotalTrucks__c += PLILoop.NumberofTrucks__c;
                }
                else{
                    chapt.TotalTrucks__c = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(ChpQuery.Proposal_Line_Items__r.size() == 0){
            chapt.TotalLinePrice__c =0;
            chapt.TotalTrucks__c = 0;
        }

        chapterList.add(chapt);
    }

    update chapterList;

}
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far? Please take a moment read about [ask] and take a [tour] of our community. We'll be glad to help you out, but we'd really like to know more specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: HI @sfdcfox , I want to know who to write the above logic in apex class and calling the apex class with required method in trigger handler.

Comment: Can we write the above logic in apex class and call it in trigger.

Comment: if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert)
    {
        APTS_ProposalLineItem_Handler.beforeInsert(Trigger.New); 
    }
    
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter)
    {
        APTS_ProposalLineItem_Handler.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter)
    {
        APTS_ProposalLineItem_Handler.afterUpdate(Trigger.New, Trigger.oldMap);
    }

Comment: like above code can we do it for my trigger

Comment: Yes, you can do code like that. What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question with any attempts you have made and where you are stuck.

Comment: just now edited it with my tried code

Comment: @sfdcfox is there any wrong with my implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class APTS_ProposalLineItem_Handler_raj {
 public static void AllAfter(list<Proposal_Line_Item__c> proli){

    set<id>  ChapterID = new set<id>();

    for (Proposal_Line_Item__c p : proli){
        if (p.chapters__c != NULL )
        {
            ChapterID.add(p.chapters__c);
        }
    }

    list<chapter__C>   ChapterList =new list<chapter__c>();

    for(chapter__C ChpQuery:[select id, TotalLinePrice__c,TotalTrucks__c, (Select Id, LinePrice__c,NumberofTrucks__c,chapters__c from Proposal_Line_Items__r where chapters__c != NULL) from chapter__c where id IN:ChapterID ])
    {
        chapter__C chapt=new chapter__C();
        chapt.id=ChpQuery.Id;
        system.debug('chpquery'+chpquery.Proposal_Line_Items__r);
        chapt.TotalLinePrice__c =0;
        chapt.TotalTrucks__c = 0;
        if(ChpQuery.Proposal_Line_Items__r.size()>0){
            for(Proposal_Line_Item__c PLILoop: ChpQuery.Proposal_Line_Items__r ){

                //Updating Line Price  on  chapters
                if(PLILoop.LinePrice__c != NULL) {
                    chapt.TotalLinePrice__c += PLILoop.LinePrice__c;

                }
                else{
                    chapt.TotalLinePrice__c = 0;
                }

                if(PLILoop.NumberofTrucks__c != NULL) {
                    chapt.TotalTrucks__c += PLILoop.NumberofTrucks__c;
                }
                else{
                    chapt.TotalTrucks__c = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(ChpQuery.Proposal_Line_Items__r.size() == 0){
            chapt.TotalLinePrice__c =0;
            chapt.TotalTrucks__c = 0;
        }

        chapterList.add(chapt);
    }
    update chapterList;
}
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/105253)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @DerekF .Just now edited it.